# What's the best way to adopt Flat UI in iOS app design?

Tags: ios, user-interface, user-experience

Since Flat UI is getting more popular. More and more apps are using Flat UI design.

Some articles about Flat UI design

[Mobile designers no longer see Apple on the forefront of iOS design.](http://gigaom.com/2013/01/04/mobile-designers-no-longer-see-apple-on-the-forefront-of-ios-design/)

[The Battle Between Flat Design And Skeuomorphism](http://sachagreif.com/flat-pixels/)

As an iOS developer not a designer, I would like to adopt Flat UI in my apps. What's the best way to adopt Flat UI in iOS app design? Let me break down this question.

1. Any Design Guideline for Flat UI design?
2. Any good articles about how to adopt Flat UI in iOS app?
3. Is any open source projects which are using Flat UI design I can refer to?
4. When I apply Flat UI in iOS apps, do I need to code each single part separately, for example, Navigation bar, Tool bar, buttons, app icon? Or I can use global code to reset the whole app to Flat UI.
5. Any good UI Mockups I can use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go with what your platform gives you. You'll fit in better. Chances are you'll also fit in better when the platform changes its own design: a standard Button control will look like the rest of the UI's buttons in the next iOS, if Apple change it, whereas if you code your own you'll be left looking odd.